$\mathbb{E}[f(T)]$ as an integral over $E$ and $\Omega$ with change of variables
I am working on the following exercise:
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and let $(E, \mathcal{E})$ and $(F, \mathcal{F})$ be measurable spaces. Let
$$ Y : (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) \to (E, \mathcal{E}) $$
be a random variable. Let
$$ T : (E, \mathcal{E}, \mathbb{P}_y) \to (F, \mathcal{F}) $$
be a measurable mapping, and let
$$ f : (F, \mathcal{F}) \to ([0, \infty], \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) $$
be a measurable function.
Then $T \circ Y : (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) \rightarrow (F, \mathcal{F})$
I have to express $\mathbb{E}[f(T)]$ as an integral over $E$ and $\Omega$.

An integral over $\Omega$, using $\mathbb{P}$, i.e.,
$$ \mathbb{E}[f(T)] = \int_\Omega f(T(Y(\omega))) \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega), $$

I've tried to express it over E. I know $T$ and $T \circ Y$ have the same distribution and T's domain is E. Therefore, i believe it should be, using LOTUS:
$$\mathbb{E}[f(T)]=\int_E f(T(x))d \mathbb{P}_y$$
with $f(T(x))$ since the domain of $f$ is $E$. I'm having trouble and i don't think this is correct? I've tried to research change of variables with no luck.

It follows easily from the definition of $\mathbb P_Y$ and simple function approximation.

Could you guide me? so $\mathbb{P}_y=\mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}(E))$, is this the correct approach?

That is correct; and it implies $\int h(Y) d\mathbb P=\int h d\mathbb P_Y$ for any non-negative measurable function $h$.

What is LOTUS ?

@KurtG I'm referring to this result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

@geetha290krm I just don't understand how $f$ can be in the integral over $E$ as it takes values from $F$, which is T's codomain. should it not be $f(T(x))$, as i presented in the question?

Already your start $$\mathbb{E}[f(T)] = \int_\Omega f(T(Y(\omega))) , d\mathbb{P}(\omega),$$ is wrong. The LHS of this should be
$\mathbb{E}[f(T\color{red}{\circ Y})],.$ It looks like you are getting confused by the composition of $T$ and $Y,.$ Write $X=T\circ Y$ and now apply LOTUS. This will integrate over $F,.$ To integrate over $E$ apply LOTUS to $Y$ only.

@KurtG if you feel like it, post an answer and i will accept it, but in the exercise i should write it as an integral over $\Omega$ and $F$ and not $E$. Also, $T$ and $T \circ Y$ obviously have the same distribution and therefore same expectation?

As long as you are asking such questions I don't feel like it. In math we have to understand things ourselves and not accept given answers. Digest what I wrote and give it a go. If you want to learn most write the integral in three different flavours: over $\Omega,E$ and $F,.$ LOTUS all the time.

Looks perfect .
